Jupyter Notebook Markdown not rendering anything
I installed Anaconda and Jupyter notebook the default way on my Windows pc and everything works fine.
However, it seems the markdown feature is not working properly.
Markdown writte:

Markdown not appearing:

I tried the listed common issues but none of them helped me.
I am expecting to find a way to fix this simple issue.

It sounds a bit like this but since you are on Windows, probably not. If kieranlul's suggestion doesn't do it, I'd suggest trying to disable an browser extensions. And if that isn't it, try disabling the Anaconda Assistant. That has been known to cause weird effects.

It could be an issue with the jupyterlab-markup package. Try uninstalling it. You don’t need jupyterlab-markup to view rendered markdown.
